# Javascript how to get selected text with its font family

Tags: javascript

I am saving selected text and its range from paragraph so i can later display it selected when open html again. I have completed all task like save its range and apply again when open it again.
So i am also saving the string which is selected from the paragraph and display it in a list so i can delete also, and for that i am using function like :->

```
var selection = window.getSelection();
var textString = selection.toString();
```

As of now it was working fine. But now i have added a multiple language in my editor. So if i save string like above the font family which is applied to selected text, its not getting display.

So i want save its font style also, so when i show selected text in list, it will render as its font style.

How can i get font family which is applied currently on selected dom. And if not font family applied on selected dom it will come from its parent.

I dont need other styles like, color , font-weight etc.

Suppose:

```
<span style="font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;>This is<span style="font-family:Conv_DevLys_040">Test content.</span><span>
```

If i select "text content" then need to apply Conv_DevLys_040 font family, if select all text then need to apply both style on particular spans.

Comment: Latest operated element by event. Get font family...

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan any sample?

Comment: A text selection could span multiple elements. So logically multiple and diverse styles. Therefore your requirement is unclear.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan i need to show the selected text in a list. So i want to get font family of particular span if its not available on that element, possible the font family comes from its parent. SO in that condition i need get it from parent node.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan simply i want to get font family from closest element which is applied.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan edited question. May be it will help you understand better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `window.getComputedStyle` on an element to get its font family; however, this method does not work on a regular text node, so a utility function `firstElementParent(node)` is required to find the first immediate parent element. You can then enclose your selection text in a span with an inline `font-family`, and insert that HTML text wherever you want:

```js
function getSelectionWithFont () {

  function firstElementParent (node) {
    while (!node.parentElement) node = node.parentNode
    return node.parentElement
  }

  var output = document.getElementById('output')
  
  var selection = window.getSelection()

  var htmlString = selection.isCollapsed ?
    selection.toString() :
    '<span style="font-family:' + window.getComputedStyle(
      firstElementParent(selection.anchorNode)
    ).fontFamily + '">' + selection + '</span>'
  
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = htmlString

}
```

```html
<p id="input" contenteditable="true" style="font-family:Georgia">Lorem ipsum dot dolor sit amet...</p>

<button onclick="getSelectionWithFont()">Get Selection with Font</button>
<p id="output"></p>
```